# how to represent graphs /trees in python and how to detect cycles?

Tags: python, algorithm

i want to implement kruskal's algorithm in python how can i go about representing the tree/graph and what approach should i follow to detect the cycles ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way of representing it (in my opinion) is by using a dict of <s>arrays</s> lists:

```
graph = {}
graph[node_id] = [other_node_id for other_node_id in neighbors(node_id)]
```

A simple way of finding cycles is by using a BF or DF search:

```
def df(node):
    if visited(node):
        pass # found a cycle here, do something with it
    visit(node)
    [df(node_id) for node_id in graph[node]]
```

*Disclaimer: this is actually a sketch; `neighbors()`, `visited()` and `visit()` are just dummies to represent how the algorithm should look like.*

Comment: by dictionary of arrays u mean dictionary of lists?

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit erm.. yes. Sorry, I misused the name ><

Answer (score 4):

[Python Graph API](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGraphApi) is a good place to start.

For example, [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) has a Kruskal's algorithm implementation to find the minimum spanning tree.

If you want to re-invent the wheel and do it yourself, that is also possible.

Comment: yes i am trying to re invent the wheel atleast this first time.